# Best way to implement global counters for highly concurrent applications?

Tags: concurrency, go

What is the best way to implement global counters for a highly concurrent application?  In my case I may have 10K-20K go routines performing "work", and I want to count the number and types of items that the routines are working on collectively...

The "classic" synchronous coding style would look like:

```
var work_counter int

func GoWorkerRoutine() {
    for {
        // do work
        atomic.AddInt32(&work_counter,1)
    }    
}
```

Now this gets more complicated because I want to track the "type" of work being done, so really I'd need something like this:

```
var work_counter map[string]int
var work_mux sync.Mutex

func GoWorkerRoutine() {
    for {
        // do work
        work_mux.Lock()
        work_counter["type1"]++
        work_mux.Unlock()
    }    
}
```

It seems like there should be a "go" optimized way using channels or something similar to this:

```
var work_counter int
var work_chan chan int // make() called somewhere else (buffered)

// started somewher else
func GoCounterRoutine() {
    for {
        select {
            case c := <- work_chan:
                work_counter += c
                break
        }
    }
}

func GoWorkerRoutine() {
    for {
        // do work
        work_chan <- 1
    }    
}
```

This last example is still missing the map, but that's easy enough to add.  Will this style provide better performance than just a simple atomic increment?  I can't tell if this is more or less complicated when we're talking about concurrent access to a global value versus something that may block on I/O to complete...

Thoughts are appreciated.

Update 5/28/2013:

I tested a couple implementations, and the results were not what I expected, here's my counter source code:

```
package helpers

import (
)

type CounterIncrementStruct struct {
    bucket string
    value int
}

type CounterQueryStruct struct {
    bucket string
    channel chan int
}

var counter map[string]int
var counterIncrementChan chan CounterIncrementStruct
var counterQueryChan chan CounterQueryStruct
var counterListChan chan chan map[string]int

func CounterInitialize() {
    counter = make(map[string]int)
    counterIncrementChan = make(chan CounterIncrementStruct,0)
    counterQueryChan = make(chan CounterQueryStruct,100)
    counterListChan = make(chan chan map[string]int,100)
    go goCounterWriter()
}

func goCounterWriter() {
    for {
        select {
            case ci := <- counterIncrementChan:
                if len(ci.bucket)==0 { return }
                counter[ci.bucket]+=ci.value
                break
            case cq := <- counterQueryChan:
                val,found:=counter[cq.bucket]
                if found {
                    cq.channel <- val
                } else {
                    cq.channel <- -1    
                }
                break
            case cl := <- counterListChan:
                nm := make(map[string]int)
                for k, v := range counter {
                    nm[k] = v
                }
                cl <- nm
                break
        }
    }
}

func CounterIncrement(bucket string, counter int) {
    if len(bucket)==0 || counter==0 { return }
    counterIncrementChan <- CounterIncrementStruct{bucket,counter}
}

func CounterQuery(bucket string) int {
    if len(bucket)==0 { return -1 }
    reply := make(chan int)
    counterQueryChan <- CounterQueryStruct{bucket,reply}
    return <- reply
}

func CounterList() map[string]int {
    reply := make(chan map[string]int)
    counterListChan <- reply
    return <- reply
}
```

It uses channels for both writes and reads which seems logical.

Here are my test cases:

```
func bcRoutine(b *testing.B,e chan bool) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        CounterIncrement("abc123",5)
        CounterIncrement("def456",5)
        CounterIncrement("ghi789",5)
        CounterIncrement("abc123",5)
        CounterIncrement("def456",5)
        CounterIncrement("ghi789",5)
    }
    e<-true
}

func BenchmarkChannels(b *testing.B) {
    b.StopTimer()
    CounterInitialize()
    e:=make(chan bool)
    b.StartTimer()

    go bcRoutine(b,e)
    go bcRoutine(b,e)
    go bcRoutine(b,e)
    go bcRoutine(b,e)
    go bcRoutine(b,e)

    <-e
    <-e
    <-e
    <-e
    <-e

}

var mux sync.Mutex
var m map[string]int
func bmIncrement(bucket string, value int) {
    mux.Lock()
    m[bucket]+=value
    mux.Unlock()
}

func bmRoutine(b *testing.B,e chan bool) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        bmIncrement("abc123",5)
        bmIncrement("def456",5)
        bmIncrement("ghi789",5)
        bmIncrement("abc123",5)
        bmIncrement("def456",5)
        bmIncrement("ghi789",5)
    }
    e<-true
}

func BenchmarkMutex(b *testing.B) {
    b.StopTimer()
    m=make(map[string]int)
    e:=make(chan bool)
    b.StartTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        bmIncrement("abc123",5)
        bmIncrement("def456",5)
        bmIncrement("ghi789",5)
        bmIncrement("abc123",5)
        bmIncrement("def456",5)
        bmIncrement("ghi789",5)
    }

    go bmRoutine(b,e)
    go bmRoutine(b,e)
    go bmRoutine(b,e)
    go bmRoutine(b,e)
    go bmRoutine(b,e)

    <-e
    <-e
    <-e
    <-e
    <-e

}
```

I implemented a simple benchmark with just a mutex around the map (just testing writes), and benchmarked both with 5 goroutines running in parallel.  Here are the results:

```
$ go test --bench=. helpers
PASS
BenchmarkChannels         100000             15560 ns/op
BenchmarkMutex   1000000              2669 ns/op
ok      helpers 4.452s
```

I would not have expected the mutex to be that much faster...

Further thoughts?

Comment: closed as duplicate of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304851/how-to-create-global-counter-in-highly-concurrent-system), pending a recommendation from the Collective, because the answers here are *not* straightforward, opinionated, and invite speculation

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't use [sync/atomic](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/) - from the linked page

> Package atomic provides low-level atomic memory primitives useful for
>   implementing synchronization algorithms.
>   These functions require great care to be used correctly. Except for
>   special, low-level applications, synchronization is better done with
>   channels or the facilities of the sync package

[Last time I had to do this](https://github.com/ncw/go-nflog-acctd) I benchmarked something which looked like your second example with a mutex and something which looked like your third example with a channel.  The channels code won when things got really busy, but make sure you make the channel buffer big.

Comment: Thanks, channels appear to be the better tool and in the end, it doesn't add much complexity for the performance benefit.

Comment: I just benchmark to find that sync/atomic.AddInt64 is slower then sync.Mutex to my problem which only have one counter per struct.I think you should benchmark before decide to use sync/atomic or sync.Mutex

Comment: I find that quote from the `sync/atomic` docs to be unsatisfying. Surely for a simple counter, `sync/atomic` is the right tool, and a channel is overkill, no?

Comment: @Flimzy yes, after benchmarking locally `sync/atomic` is 2.5-6 times faster than multiple channel's based implementations
2.5 times faster with GOMAXPROCS channel consumers and 1 final on-demand aggregation
6 times faster with a single channel

Comment: -1. Channels are a thread-safe queue that works internally with sync primitives like mutexes and condition variables. Using that to increment a bloody number, instead of the most basic and fastest primitive there is - an atomic - seems extremely ill-advised, but also completely par for the course for the go community. There are hardware-level instructions for atomic compare-and-swap. It takes countless cycles to operate a whole thread-safe-queue in comparison.

Comment: @JonathanHall You'd be correct in the context of any other programming lang and its sync primitives. However, go's entire philosophy and documentation is based on the idea that understanding things is for nerds and that problems go away by making sure you never learn about them. In this paradigm, a thread-safe queue is obviously the tool to increment a number. Also, since channels are "magic", they fit neatly into the idea of "don't communicate by sharing memory, share memory by communicating" because gophers can pretend that channels are something different than sharing memory with a lock.

Comment: @JMC Yeah, there's just no way I agree with that. The amount of understanding (not to mention code) necessary to increment a counter with a channel far exceeds that of an atomic increment.

Comment: @JonathanHall I was being entirely sarcastic and agree with you. I was making fun of go's documentation and underlying ideology that leads people to think aromics are scary and dangerous and that channels are the solution to every problem.

Answer (score 38):

If you're trying to synchronize a pool of workers (e.g. allow n goroutines to crunch away at some amount of work) then channels are a very good way to go about it, but if all you actually need is a counter (e.g page views) then they are overkill. The [sync](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/) and [sync/atomic](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/) packages are there to help.

```
import "sync/atomic"

type count32 int32

func (c *count32) inc() int32 {
    return atomic.AddInt32((*int32)(c), 1)
}

func (c *count32) get() int32 {
    return atomic.LoadInt32((*int32)(c))
}
```

[Go Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/1eDuXo2BkoO)

Answer (score 11):

Don't be afraid of using mutexes and locks just because you think they're "not proper Go". In your second example it's absolutely clear what's going on, and that counts for a lot. You will have to try it yourself to see how contented that mutex is, and whether adding complication will increase performance.

If you do need increased performance, perhaps sharding is the best way to go:
http://play.golang.org/p/uLirjskGeN

The downside is that your counts will only be as up-to-date as your sharding decides. There may also be performance hits from calling `time.Since()` so much, but, as always, measure it first :)

Comment: Mutexes are a lower-level primitive and have their own useful niche, but they are not compositional in the same way that CSP-designed channel usage is. So if in doubt, use channels.

Answer (score 8):

The other answer using sync/atomic is suited for things like page counters, but not for submitting unique identifiers to an external API. To do that, you need an "increment-and-return" operation, which can only be implemented as a CAS loop.

Here's a CAS loop around an int32 to generate unique message IDs:

```golang
import "sync/atomic"

type UniqueID struct {
    counter int32
}

func (c *UniqueID) Get() int32 {
    for {
        val := atomic.LoadInt32(&c.counter)
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&c.counter, val, val+1) {
            return val
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, simply do:

```
requestID := client.msgID.Get()
form.Set("id", requestID)
```

This has an advantage over channels in that it doesn't require as many extra idle resources - existing goroutines are used as they ask for IDs rather than using one goroutine for every counter your program needs.

TODO: Benchmark against channels. I'm going to guess that channels are worse in the no-contention case and better in the high-contention case, as they have queuing while this code simply spins attempting to win the race.

Answer (score 7):

Old question but I just stumbled upon this and it may help: https://github.com/uber-go/atomic

Basically the engineers at Uber has built a few nice util functions on top of the `sync/atomic` package

I haven't tested this in production yet but the codebase is very small and the implementation of [most functions](https://github.com/uber-go/atomic/blob/ca680462431f8c7f96686d91b1d9e5203c4b075b/atomic.go#L288) is quite [stock standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap#Example_application:_atomic_adder)

Definitely preferred over using channels or basic mutexes

Answer (score 3):

The last one was close:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 3)
    go GoCounterRoutine(ch)
    go GoWorkerRoutine(1, ch)
    // not run as goroutine because mein() would just end
    GoWorkerRoutine(2, ch)

}

// started somewhere else
func GoCounterRoutine(ch chan int) {
    counter := 0
    for {
        ch <- counter
        counter += 1
    }
}

func GoWorkerRoutine(n int, ch chan int) {
    var seq int
    for seq := range ch {
        // do work:
        fmt.Println(n, seq)
    }
}
```

This introduces a single point of failure: if the counter goroutine dies, everything is lost. This may not be a problem if all goroutine are executed on one computer, but may become a problem if they are scattered over the network. To make the counter immune to failures of single nodes in the cluster, [special algorithms](http://www.iis.sinica.edu.tw/page/jise/2006/200609_16.pdf) have to be used.

Answer (score 3):

I implemented this with a simple map + mutex which seems to be the best way to handle this since it is the "simplest way" (which is what Go says to use to choose locks vs channels).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type single struct {
    mu     sync.Mutex
    values map[string]int64
}

var counters = single{
    values: make(map[string]int64),
}

func (s *single) Get(key string) int64 {
    s.mu.Lock()
    defer s.mu.Unlock()
    return s.values[key]
}

func (s *single) Incr(key string) int64 {
    s.mu.Lock()
    defer s.mu.Unlock()
    s.values[key]++
    return s.values[key]
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(counters.Incr("bar"))
    fmt.Println(counters.Incr("bar"))
    fmt.Println(counters.Incr("bar"))
    fmt.Println(counters.Get("foo"))
    fmt.Println(counters.Get("bar"))

}
```

You can run the code on https://play.golang.org/p/9bDMDLFBAY.
I made a simple packaged version [on gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/Xeoncross/1acefb134973e3abe590)

Answer (score 2):

see by yourself and let me know what you think.

**src/test/helpers/helpers.go**

```golang
package helpers

type CounterIncrementStruct struct {
    bucket string
    value  int
}

type CounterQueryStruct struct {
    bucket  string
    channel chan int
}

var counter map[string]int
var counterIncrementChan chan CounterIncrementStruct
var counterQueryChan chan CounterQueryStruct
var counterListChan chan chan map[string]int

func CounterInitialize() {
    counter = make(map[string]int)
    counterIncrementChan = make(chan CounterIncrementStruct, 0)
    counterQueryChan = make(chan CounterQueryStruct, 100)
    counterListChan = make(chan chan map[string]int, 100)
    go goCounterWriter()
}

func goCounterWriter() {
    for {
        select {
        case ci := <-counterIncrementChan:
            if len(ci.bucket) == 0 {
                return
            }
            counter[ci.bucket] += ci.value
            break
        case cq := <-counterQueryChan:
            val, found := counter[cq.bucket]
            if found {
                cq.channel <- val
            } else {
                cq.channel <- -1
            }
            break
        case cl := <-counterListChan:
            nm := make(map[string]int)
            for k, v := range counter {
                nm[k] = v
            }
            cl <- nm
            break
        }
    }
}

func CounterIncrement(bucket string, counter int) {
    if len(bucket) == 0 || counter == 0 {
        return
    }
    counterIncrementChan <- CounterIncrementStruct{bucket, counter}
}

func CounterQuery(bucket string) int {
    if len(bucket) == 0 {
        return -1
    }
    reply := make(chan int)
    counterQueryChan <- CounterQueryStruct{bucket, reply}
    return <-reply
}

func CounterList() map[string]int {
    reply := make(chan map[string]int)
    counterListChan <- reply
    return <-reply
}
```

**src/test/distributed/distributed.go**

```golang
package distributed

type Counter struct {
    buckets map[string]int
    incrQ   chan incrQ
    readQ   chan readQ
    sumQ    chan chan int
}

func New() Counter {
    c := Counter{
        buckets: make(map[string]int, 100),
        incrQ:   make(chan incrQ, 1000),
        readQ:   make(chan readQ, 0),
        sumQ:    make(chan chan int, 0),
    }
    go c.run()
    return c
}

func (c Counter) run() {
    for {
        select {
        case a := <-c.readQ:
            a.res <- c.buckets[a.bucket]
        case a := <-c.sumQ:
            var sum int
            for _, cnt := range c.buckets {
                sum += cnt
            }
            a <- sum
        case a := <-c.incrQ:
            c.buckets[a.bucket] += a.count
        }
    }
}

func (c Counter) Get(bucket string) int {
    res := make(chan int)
    c.readQ <- readQ{bucket: bucket, res: res}
    return <-res
}

func (c Counter) Sum() int {
    res := make(chan int)
    c.sumQ <- res
    return <-res
}

type readQ struct {
    bucket string
    res    chan int
}

type incrQ struct {
    bucket string
    count  int
}

func (c Counter) Agent(bucket string, limit int) *Agent {
    a := &Agent{
        bucket:   bucket,
        limit:    limit,
        sendIncr: c.incrQ,
    }
    return a
}

type Agent struct {
    bucket   string
    limit    int
    count    int
    sendIncr chan incrQ
}

func (a *Agent) Incr(n int) {
    a.count += n
    if a.count > a.limit {
        select {
        case a.sendIncr <- incrQ{bucket: a.bucket, count: a.count}:
            a.count = 0
        default:
        }
    }
}

func (a *Agent) Done() {
    a.sendIncr <- incrQ{bucket: a.bucket, count: a.count}
    a.count = 0
}
```

**src/test/helpers_test.go**

```golang
package counters

import (
    "sync"
    "testing"
)

var mux sync.Mutex
var m map[string]int

func bmIncrement(bucket string, value int) {
    mux.Lock()
    m[bucket] += value
    mux.Unlock()
}

func BenchmarkMutex(b *testing.B) {
    b.StopTimer()
    m = make(map[string]int)
    buckets := []string{
        "abc123",
        "def456",
        "ghi789",
    }
    b.StartTimer()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(b.N)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        go func() {
            for _, b := range buckets {
                bmIncrement(b, 5)
            }
            for _, b := range buckets {
                bmIncrement(b, 5)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

**src/test/distributed_test.go**

```golang
package counters

import (
    "sync"
    "test/counters/distributed"
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkDistributed(b *testing.B) {
    b.StopTimer()
    counter := distributed.New()
    agents := []*distributed.Agent{
        counter.Agent("abc123", 100),
        counter.Agent("def456", 100),
        counter.Agent("ghi789", 100),
    }
    b.StartTimer()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(b.N)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        go func() {
            for _, a := range agents {
                a.Incr(5)
            }
            for _, a := range agents {
                a.Incr(5)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    for _, a := range agents {
        a.Done()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

**results**

```sh
$ go test --bench=. --count 10 -benchmem
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: test/counters
BenchmarkDistributed-4       3356620           351 ns/op          24 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       3414073           368 ns/op          11 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       3371878           374 ns/op           7 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       3240631           387 ns/op           3 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       3169230           389 ns/op           2 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       3177606           386 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       3064552           390 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       3065877           409 ns/op           2 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       2924686           400 ns/op           1 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       3049873           389 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4             1000000          1106 ns/op          17 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4              948331          1246 ns/op           9 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4             1000000          1244 ns/op          12 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4             1000000          1246 ns/op          11 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4             1000000          1228 ns/op           1 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4             1000000          1235 ns/op           2 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4             1000000          1244 ns/op           1 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4             1000000          1214 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4              956024          1233 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4             1000000          1213 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      test/counters   37.461s
```

If you change the limit value to 1000, the code gets much faster, instantly without worries

```sh
$ go test --bench=. --count 10 -benchmem
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: test/counters
BenchmarkDistributed-4       5463523           221 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       5455981           220 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       5591240           213 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       5277915           212 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       5430421           213 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       5374153           226 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       5656743           219 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       5337343           211 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       5353845           217 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDistributed-4       5416137           217 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4             1000000          1002 ns/op         135 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4             1253211          1141 ns/op          58 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4             1000000          1261 ns/op           3 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4              987345          1678 ns/op          59 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4              925371          1247 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4             1000000          1259 ns/op           2 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4              978800          1248 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4              982144          1213 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4              975681          1254 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4              994789          1205 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      test/counters   34.314s
```

Changing Counter.incrQ length will also greatly affect performance, though it is more memory.

Answer (score 0):

If your work counter types are not dynamic, i.e. you can write them all out upfront, I don't think you'll get much simpler or faster than this.

No mutex, no channel, no map. Just a statically sized array and an enum.

```
type WorkType int

const (
    WorkType1 WorkType = iota
    WorkType2
    WorkType3
    WorkType4
    NumWorkTypes
)

var workCounter [NumWorkTypes]int64

func updateWorkCount(workType WorkType, delta int) {
    atomic.AddInt64(&workCounter[workType], int64(delta))
}
```

Usage like so:

```
updateWorkCount(WorkType1, 1)
```

If you need to sometimes work with work types as strings for display purposes, you can always generate code with a tool like [stringer](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer)