# Is there a way to reset counter incremented using atomic.AddUint64?

Tags: go, mutex, atomic

I am implementing global counters for a concurrent go application.

My use case is that the counter should be reset after x seconds and written to DB.

I have tried using mutex (I am able to reset counter using this)

Also when I increment the counter I also log something.
I have found that after the application runs for about 8-9 hours the number of lines logged and the counter value do not match (mutex version) Counter values is always less.
I have still not found the cause for this.

I am using mutex in the following manner

```golang
func (s *Metrics) AddQps() {
    s.qpsMu.Lock()
    s.qps++
    s.qpsMu.Unlock()
}


And the flushing of metrics is done as follows.

for {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Duration(interval) * time.Second)
    select {
    case <-ticker.C:
       logger.Println("flushing metrics...")
    }
}
```

I had implemented the mutex part referencing 
[[How to create global counter in golang in highly concurrent system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304851/how-to-create-global-counter-in-golang-in-highly-concurrent-system])

Due to the above mentioned problem I am now trying counters using sync.atomic.
As I want the metric to be flushed after x seconds I wanted to reset the counter.

Comment: And what's the problem, exactly?

Comment: I'd suggest you to take a look at https://github.com/anatolygudkov/mc4go as an example. This is thread safe counters which can be read even from another process...

Answer (score 2):

So what is the problem to use something like this?

```
func TestNameAtomic(t *testing.T) {
    var i int64

    atomic.AddInt64(&i, 1)
    atomic.AddInt64(&i, 1)
    atomic.AddInt64(&i, 1)
    fmt.Println(i)

    atomic.CompareAndSwapInt64(&i, i, 0)
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```